# Using the WaveformTimeline Control in the WPF Sound Visualisation Library

Tags: c#, naudio, wpf-4.0, audio-processing

I am having problems using the `WaveformTimeLine` class in the [WPF Sound Visualization Library](http://wpfsvl.codeplex.com/documentation) using the NAUDIO class library.I have followed the instructions they have put out in their documentation but it's just not working for me.

My code behind looks like:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private OpenFileDialog dialogBox = new OpenFileDialog();

        private void open_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //Get Audio File
            dialogBox.Filter = "Wave File (*.mp3 ; *.wav) | *.mp3;*.wav;";
            if (dialogBox.ShowDialog() == true)
            {
                NAudioEngine.Instance.OpenFile(dialogBox.FileName);
                fileLocation = dialogBox.FileName;
            }

            var soundEngine = NAudioEngine.Instance;
            soundEngine.PropertyChanged += NAudioEngine_PropertyChanged;
            soundEngine.OpenFile(fileLocation);
            if (NAudioEngine.Instance.CanPlay) NAudioEngine.Instance.Play();
            myWave = new WaveformTimeline();
            myWave.RegisterSoundPlayer(soundEngine);
        }
```

The code doesn't throw any errors but it also doesn't do anything too.Can someone with experience with this API or similar APIs please help me solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Key mistake was the line

```
myWave = new WaveformTimeline();
```

After adding the WaveformTimeline control in XAML design view, you don't initialise the control again in the code behind because you will be given another instance of the WaveformTimeline object.