# Displaying WaveformTimeline Control in WPF Sound Visualization Library

Tags: c#, wpf, naudio

My problem is simple. I want to import an audio file, and once imported, display a waveform of the audio using the Sound Visualization Library's WaveformTimeline Control.

```
string[] files = open.FileNames;

foreach (string file in files)
{
    wave = new NAudio.Wave.WaveFileReader(file);
    output = new NAudio.Wave.DirectSoundOut();
    output.Init(new NAudio.Wave.WaveChannel32(wave));
    output.Pause();
                                                                                           
    WaveformPlot.BeginInit();
    WaveformPlot = new WaveformTimeline();
    WaveformPlot.RegisterSoundPlayer();
}
```

I am almost there, but I can't figure out what to pass the `RegisterSoundPlayer()` method. I have looked in the library's documentation and in its code. I know it needs an instance of the player somehow, as shown in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17146255/using-the-waveformtimeline-control-in-the-wpf-sound-visualisation-library) question, but the names seem to have been changed since then.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need [jacobjohnston/wpfsvl](https://github.com/jacobjohnston/wpfsvl)

> The WPF Sound Visualization Library is a collection of WPF Controls for graphically displaying data related to sound processing. Current controls include a Spectrum Analyzer, Waveform Timeline, and an Album Art Display Panel.
> Most of the WPF Sound Visualization Library controls were created to power my other project, BPMinus. Check it out.

Answer (score 0):

In your mainwindow.xaml file add;

```
 xmlns:xmlns:svl="clr-namespace:WPFSoundVisualizationLib;assembly=WPFSoundVisualizationLib"
```

and in the location you want to add the control you would use;

```
<svl:WaveformTimeline x:name="svlWaveform" />
```

in your code behind to initialize it is as simple as;

```
NAudioEngine soundEngine = NAudioEngine.Instance;
svlWaveform.RegisterSoundPlayer(soundEngine);
```